# Double Buffered Mdi Container?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to set a double buffer form being a mdi container at the same time?

I've tried to draw the controls but it doesn't active the double buffer feature, so my graphics are blinking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MdiContainer` is just a `Form` with `IsMdiContainer` being `true`. So you just set `DoubleBuffered = true` on that form.

If you mean `MdiClient`, I think you have to try using `Reflection` like this:

```
typeof(MdiClient).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                 .SetValue(yourForm.Controls.OfType<MdiClient>().First(), true, null);
```

Comment: It doesn't work since the background goes gray (if set true), and its not drawing anything..

Comment: @JorgeTovar that's not `MdiContainer` itself, it's `MdiClient`

Answer (score 0):

dosent work for me... only works for me:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = API.WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_COMPOSITED;//| API.WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_LAYERED;

            return cp;
        }
    }
```

but with this problems

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488865/non-client-area-buttons-maximize-minimize-close-do-not-glow